# How to make a wireless modem using a normal Wi-Fi router and a 4g usb modem

Tags: electrical-engineering, circuits, telecommunication, wireless-communication, software

I have a normal TP link (Model: TL-WR841N) router and an USB 4g modem. But the WIFI router does not have any USB port. I want to connect the USB modem with the router, want to share internet wirelessly.  Is it possible to connect?

Comment: Can you please share specifications of your USB 4G Modem?

Comment: Short answer: no this will not be possible. Or rather it is probably technically possible but it will be FAR from plug-and-play.

Answer (score -1):

Amazon has a USB to ethernet adapter for $9.99.

[image: figure]

here is the link:

[adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ET4KHJ2)

Comment: My suspicion is the USB 4G modem might not mate with the connector shown on our image.

Comment: The USB modem would be a client, not a host, so this adapter would not work.